# Query Postgres for number of items in JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am running Postgres 9.3 and have a problem with a query involving a JSON column that I cannot seem to crack.

Let's assume this is the table:

```
# CREATE TABLE aa (a int, b json);
# INSERT INTO aa VALUES (1, '{"f1":1,"f2":true}');
# INSERT INTO aa VALUES (2, '{"f1":2,"f2":false,"f3":"Hi I''m \"Dave\""}');
# INSERT INTO aa VALUES (3, '{"f1":3,"f2":true,"f3":"Hi I''m \"Popo\""}');
```

**I now want to create a query that returns all rows that have exactly three items/keys in the root node of the JSON column (i.e., row 2 and 3).** Whether the JSON is nested doesn't matter.

I tried to use `json_object_keys` and `json_each` but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Define "number of items" more precisely, please. Attributes in the root node? Do nested elements count?

Comment: Yes, attributes in the root node is what I meant. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`json_each(json)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-TABLE) should do the job. Counting only root elements:

```
SELECT aa.*
FROM   aa, json_each(aa.b) elem
GROUP  BY aa.a   -- possible, because it's the PK!
HAVING count(*) = 3;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/46925/1)